# Why R Markdown Caption cannot take "&"

Tags: r, pdf, latex, markdown

I am gradually building an R Markdown (.RMD) file, learning by doing. I was able to insert a couple of tables, but I had a problem with one of them. The initial setup is:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "5/10/2021"
output: bookdown::pdf_book
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,
               fig_align = "left",
               fig_width = 7,
               fig_height = 7,
               dev = "png",
               cache = FALSE)
```
````

The original code that generated an error was

````
```{r sphistperf}
kable(stock_index_stats,
      format="latex",
      caption="S&P Historical Performance Statistics")
```
````

The error message is:

```
output file: TestCenter.knit.md

! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<argument> ...}{\relax }}\label {tab:sphistperf}S&
                                                  P Historical Performance S...
l.202 ...rf}S&P Historical Performance Statistics}

Error: LaTeX failed to compile TestCenter.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See TestCenter.log for more info.
Error during wrapup: 
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

The problem is fixed if I remove the "&" from the caption, which becomes

```
caption="SP Historical Performance Statistics"
```

Still, I want the "&" in my caption. Is there a way to keep it? I tried putting an escape character "" before it and that did not work. Any suggestions on how to keep the "&"?

Comment: Can you use `caption="S\\&P Historical Performance Statistics")`

Comment: To expand on the spot on comment from @akrun: `&` is a special character for latex, which is e.g. used in tables to separate the cells. So to use it, you need to escape it with `\&` and then one more \ for whatever rmarkdown does before generating the tex code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters), there are some characters that needs escaping

[image]

---

Here, is a tested version of the markdown code

````
---
title: "testing"
author: "akrun"
date: "10/05/2021"
output: bookdown::pdf_book
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
library(kableExtra)
kable(summary(cars), format = 'latex',  caption="Dummy S\\&P Performance")
```
````

-output

[image]